# save all word permutations that are in a sentence in to a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to save all word *permutations* that are in a sentence in to a list.

I want to use this for autocomplete.

For example:
`s = "Stackoverflow is a platform"`

When I split by a whitespace. I get ['Stackoverflow', 'is', 'a', 'platform'] and use the list as suggestions.

It only worked if I type `Stackoverflow` but it wouldn't suggest anything if I type `Stackoverflow is`

I want it to be saved as:
`list = ['Stackoverflow', 'Stackoverflow is','Stackoverflow is a', 'Stackoverflow is a platform']`

Comment: How do you define *word*?

Comment: Why not `'Stackoverflow is a`', or `'a platform'`, or `'is a'`?

Comment: "Stackoverflow is a platform" is a sentence. "Stackoverflow" is a word, "is" is a word @Daweo

Comment: @ateleh Then why isn't `'is'` one of the elements of your list?

Comment: Please try to draft some code - possibly using a string's `split()` method, and edit the question to include the sample code, its incorrect output, and what you want the output to be.

Comment: I want it for autocomplete. It has to be [words1, word1 word2, word1 word2 word3 etc.]

Comment: @ateleh you still did not define what is a word. Are you just using every whitespace as a separator? What about "words" that contain whitespace like some names like "Stack Overflow" instead of "Stackoverflow"? Unclear what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
s = "Stackoverflow is a platform"
L = s.split(' ')
K = [' '.join(L[0:i]) for i in range(1,len(L)+1)]
print(K)
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering your case I hope this solution might helps.

if you use split function you can get each word as separated in a list. for example.

```
st = "Stackoverflow is a platform"
print(st.split())
```

output will be

```
['Stackoverflow', 'is', 'a', 'platform']
```

for your case, using for loop may give you the desired output.

```
st = "Stackoverflow is a platform"
res = []
j = 0
for i in range(len(st)):
    if st[i] == " ":
        res.append(st[j:i])
res.append(st)
print(res)
```

this output will be

```
['Stackoverflow', 'Stackoverflow is', 'Stackoverflow is a', 'Stackoverflow is a platform']
```

Hope this is what you are expecting I think. thanks

Answer (score 0):

here a code snippet that should do the work:

```
phrase = "Stackoverflow is a platform".split(" ")
word_list = [phrase[0:i] for i in range(len(phrase)+1)]
word_list.pop(0)

print(word_list)
```

note that in your example expected value with this function you have one more result:
[['Stackoverflow'], ['Stackoverflow', 'is'], ['Stackoverflow', 'is', 'a'], ['Stackoverflow', 'is', 'a', 'platform']]

in case that you don't want the values inside a list this snipped here should also work:

```
phrase = "Stackoverflow is a platform".split()
word_complete = [' '.join(phrase[0:i]) for i in range(1, len(phrase)+1)]
```

result:
['Stackoverflow', 'Stackoverflow is', 'Stackoverflow is a', 'Stackoverflow is a platform']